# adding a shell extension for selected text

Tags: c#, selection, windows-shell

I'm trying to add a Windows Shell shortcut (right click context menu item) so anywhere in Windows, when I have text selected this item will appear. I cannot find the Registry item to alter/add or what to put there to get this to occur.

The selected text needs to also be passed to my application as an argument some how. I will be selecting some ID numbers, then manipulating those in the project.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i begin writing a windows shell extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391334/how-do-i-begin-writing-a-windows-shell-extension)

Comment: Is what you suggest even possible without doing some really crazy hooking? I know you can write shell extensions for right-clicking on files, but for like text in Notepad or Firefox?

Comment: "...have text selected" as in "add entry to cut/copy/paste context menus"? I don't think it is possible. Please clarify what menus and if "anywhere in Windows" is limited to explorer or all programs.

Comment: @L.B I don't think it is duplicate, so far sounds like misuse of "shell extension" term.

Comment: One last comment: as of 2012 Shell extensions written in managed code are [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (article contains some invalid reasons, but statement is true, article hopefully will be updated... eventually... I can't do much about it even working at Microsoft).

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not possible. Context menus are unique to each application. There is no standard, system-generated Copy/Paste context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to create the shell extension which will allow you to inject into the any textbox's context menu.

The most you can do is to hook up the window creating API, filter out everything except context menu creation (WPF windows go down) and then do whatever you want to.